# How to wash soft fruit?

Tags: fruit

I bought a pack of blackberries from the supermraket and the label said to wash before use. I tried that and it completely ruined them.

I tried running them under a tap (faucet). Ruined. I tried dropping the fruit into a bowl of water. Ruined. I tried running them under a slow trickle of water. Not ruined but also not washed.

How, please, am I supposed to wash soft fruit like blackberries?

Comment: How were they "ruined"? I've washed blackberries by dropping them into water a few times, and at least for me and my kids they still tasted great :)

Comment: They were mostly squashed or burst after being dropped into the water and fished out.

Comment: Sounds like they were over-ripe

Comment: Maybe - I had just bought them from the supermarket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to just gently pour the blackberries into a basket strainer, then lower the strainer into a bowl of water. Then you can just lift the strainer out and the berries will come with it, no fishing required.